# Not able to select value from drop down menu

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

https://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/register.php

I was trying to automate the drop down country menu on this page but am unable to select any value from the drop down.

[image: code used]

Eclipse is throwing the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.getDomAttribute(java.lang.String)'
> at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.(Select.java:54)
> at ui.DropDown1.main(DropDown1.java:23)

I can click on the drop down menu but it does not select any value. neither does it print the values of drop down menu stored in `List<WebElements>`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have created the Select object will need change

```
Select countrySel=new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country")));
countrySel.selectByValue("Antarctica");
```

I hope this should help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the problem statement, I think we have 2 different requirements here:

1. Print out List containing values.
2. Fetch value = "ANTARCTICA" from country drop down.

// Code

```
package TestScripts;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class selectValue {
    
    //Object declaration
    public static FirefoxDriver ffdr = null;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        
        // Creating instance of Firefox Driver
        ffdr = new FirefoxDriver();
        
        // to open given URL using firefox driver with get non static method
        ffdr.get("https://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/register.php");
        
        System.out.println("Inside BeforeClass");
        
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("Inside AfterClass end of program.");
        //quits the entire browser session with all its tabs and windows
        ffdr.quit();
        
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        
        
        /*To print out list you can do it in this way.
         * */
        List<WebElement> drop = ffdr.findElements(By.xpath("//select[@name='country']"));
        System.out.println(drop.get(0).getText());
        
        /*To select value we can easily identify by this way by name.
         * */
        WebElement cntry = ffdr.findElement(By.name("country"));
        Select drpcntry = new Select(cntry);
        drpcntry.selectByValue("ANTARCTICA");
        
        /*
        String[] words=drop.get(0).getText().toString().split("\\n");//splits the string based on New line  
        //using java for each loop to print elements of string array  
        for(String w:words){  
            System.out.println(w);
        } */ 
                
    }
}
```

I hope, this satisfied your expectations.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is faced by every qa person in automation testing services company.

Firstly, As your dropdown tag is Select, you can select value directly by using `selectByValue`, `selectByVisibleText` like below without clicking the dropdown:

```
Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country")));

s.selectByValue("Antarctica");
```

Secondly for capturing the dropdown values use below code:

```
  // getting the list of options in the dropdown with getOptions()
  List <WebElement> op = s.getOptions();
  int size = op.size();
  for(int i =0; i<size ; i++){
     String options = op.get(i).getText();
     System.out.println(options);
  }
```